# How to correctly bind a component property that is updated by a webservice in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple page that gets its data from a set of web services and they are called in an interval. I want to update the page every time the web services gets new data.

My current issue is that while I am getting the data but the child component are not updating themselves and are not showing themselves at all. I have also tried this with static data which works correctly so I am guessing that I am not binding the properties correctly.

Below is the html and script pages

```
   <div class="columns" id="app">
        <div class="column">                    
         <process-list  v-bind:processesInfo="serverProcesses"></process-list>                         
        </div>
        <div class="column">

          <article class="message is-info">
            <div class="message-header">
              <p>System info</p>
            </div>
            <div class="message-body">
                    <pre> <code>  {{ memoryResponse }} </code></pre> 
                    <pre>memory and Storage info </pre>
            </div>
          </article>

        </div>
        </div>
```

script

```
Vue.config.devtools = true
Vue.component('process-info', {
template:' <article class="message is-info">' +
            ' <div class="message-header">' +
            '   <p> {{ process.Process }} id: {{ process.ProcessID }}</p>' +
            ' </div>' +
            ' <div class="message-body">' +               
            '  <ul>' +   
            '     <li><strong>I/O Writes (Bytes per sec) : </strong> {{ process.IOWrites }} </li>' +
            '     <li><strong>Virtual Bytes : </strong>  {{ process.VirtualBytes }} </li>'+
            '     <li><strong>Virtual Bytes Peak : </strong>  {{ process.VirtualBytesPeak }}</li>'+
            '     <li><strong>Working Set : </strong>  {{ process.WorkingSet }}</li>'+
            '     <li><strong>Working Set Peak : </strong> {{ process.WorkingSetPeak }}</li> '+
            '     <li><strong>% Processor Time : </strong> {{ process.ProcessorTime }}</li>' +                
            '  </ul>' +   
            ' </div>' +
           ' </article>',
   props:['process']
    });

 Vue.component('process-list', {
 template:' <div><div v-for="process in processesInfo"> ' +
            ' <process-info v-bind:process="process"></process-info>'+
          '</div></div>' ,                      
 props:['processesInfo'],              
//  watch:{
//      processesInfo(value) {
//          this.myProps = value.Processes
//      }
//  },
//  data() {
//      return {
//        /*   processesInfo: [
//             {"Process": "edmserver","ProcessID": "20792","IOWrites": "267","VirtualBytes": "4.294967E+09 MB","VirtualBytesPeak": "4.294967E+09 MB","WorkingSet": "1.387725E+07 MB","WorkingSetPeak": "3.692052E+08 MB","ProcessorTime": "0"}, 
//             {"Process": "edmappserver","ProcessID": "17372","IOWrites": "96","VirtualBytes": "4.294967E+09 MB","VirtualBytesPeak": "4.294967E+09 MB","WorkingSet": "5.326848E+07 MB","WorkingSetPeak": "8.826388E+08 MB","ProcessorTime": "0"}

//         ] */    
//      }                
//  },


}) 

var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {            
    serverProcesses : [],
    serverInfo : null,
    backupResponce : 'No data!',
    memoryResponse : 'No data!',
    edmStatusInterval: null,       
    edmStatusAttemptNumber : 0,        
    interval : 5000
},
methods: {
    pullingEDMstatus : function() {
        this.edmStatusInterval = setInterval(this.checkEDMstatus, this.interval);   
    }, 
    stopPullings : function() {
        clearInterval(this.edmStatusInterval);         
    },
    checkEDMstatus : function() {                   
        this.edmStatusAttemptNumber += 1;              
        fetch(getEDMstatusUrl(), {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {                                                
                this.serverProcesses = JSON.stringify(data.Processes, null, 4)
                this.serverInfo = JSON.stringify(data.System, null, 4)
            })      
        .catch(error => { 
            if(error.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
                generateErrorMsg('503','Service Unavailable')
            } else {
                generateErrorMsg('', error.message) 
            }
        })
    } 
},
beforeDestroy() {
      clearInterval(this,polling)
},
created() {
      this.pullingEDMstatus()         
}      
})
```

I tried to use the v-bind but this does not work here and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Also I have read that I need to use a watch when the parent property is updated but again did not work for me.

By the way this is my first attempt with `vuejs` so links and examples are appreciated.

cheers,

es

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` produces a String - but `v-for` does not work on Strings, only on Arrays and Objects.

Comment: @IVOGELOV you are correct I didn't need to use JSON.stringify() at all, but even after removing it this.serverProcesses = data.Processes the component is not shown.

Comment: If you can create a snippet on CodeSandbox I can try to make it work.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks a lot.    https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-shamir-24pwm, I didn't know how to simulate the ws so I added a sample data file.

Comment: It seems that your project is not properly setup - you have custom element (process-list) inside your DOM template, so it is not rendered. Consider using Single-File components.

Comment: found the solution, put everything inside the component itself :-)  also there was a problem with the dot notation for my json object, I had to use the x['cc'] method instead of x.cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem I moved the methods from the main to the components themselves

```
Vue.component('process-list', {
 template:' <div><div v-for="process in processesInfo"> ' +                 
            ' <process-info v-bind:process="process"></process-info>'+
          '</div></div>' ,                        
 data() {
     return {
        processesInfo : [],
        statusInterval: null, 
        interval : 5000
     }                
 },
 methods: {        
    pullingStatus : function() {
        this.statusInterval = setInterval(this.checkStatus, this.interval);   
    },        
    checkStatus : function() {                   
        this.statusAttemptNumber += 1;              
        fetch(getStatusUrl(), {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {                                                
                this.processesInfo = data.Processes                  
            })      
        .catch(error => { 
            if(error.message === 'Failed to fetch') {
                generateErrorMsg('503','Service Unavailable')
            } else {
                generateErrorMsg('', error.message) 
            }
        })
    } 
},
beforeDestroy() {
      clearInterval(this,polling)
},
created() {
      this.pullingStatus()         
}      


}) 

var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {                   
    serverInfo : null,
    backupResponce : 'No data!',
    memoryResponse : 'No data!',       
    statusAttemptNumber : 0,        

}
})
```

cheers,

es